# What purpose does ある serve in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, words

I'm just getting into trying to read Japanese literature and I came across this sentence on the opening page of ゆきの物語第一章.

> [昔々]{むかし}、ある[小]{ちい}さな[村]{むら}にゆきという[娘]{むすめ}がおばあさんと[二人]{ふたり}で[暮]{く}らしていました。

I have roughly translated this as:

> *Once upon a time, a daughter, called Yuki, and her grandmother lived together in a small village.*

However, I have no idea why ある is required in this sentence. (Any help with the translation would also be greatly appreciated)

Comment: So is the ひ optional for style? I'm confused.

Comment: I think the accepted answer in the link answers this question too: "「ある」, all by itself, can mean 'one ~~' or 'a certain ~~' ".

Comment: Okay thank you, is my translation otherwise correct?

Comment: Yes, but it may be better to translate this 娘 as "young lady".